# Model [FromBody] and Guid mapping in Web Api 2

Tags: c#, guid, asp.net-web-api2

I'm implementing web api 2 and I found strange behaviour of the Guid mapping. Here is my problem definition

This is my model example

```
public class MyModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have following action on my controller where I have MyModel as input [FromBody]

```
[HttpPost, Route("create")]
public IHttpActionResult Create([FromBody]MyModel model)
{
    // some implementation
}
```

Everything works fine instead of Guid mapping. When I post JSON of a new MyModel in the request body :

```
{
    "Id":"1d93dfa2-sb34-403d-a766-bdcf1cf47a71",
    "Name":"name"
}
```

Name is set correctly as "name" but the Guid is every time generated as a new Guid.

What can cause this issue please ? How can I set correct mapping of the Guid value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `1d93dfa2-sb34-403d-a766-bdcf1cf47a71` is not a valid Guid.

Guids only contain `0-9` and `a-f`, whereas your string has an `s` in it and is therefore not a valid Guid so the Model Binder does not bind anything to that property in your model.

Comment: Yes you're right. I modify a -> s instead of a -> d by mistake. Nevertheless, I would expect exception not new guid in this case.

Comment: When you say "new guid" is it `9a3fb67d-cc00-409e-b7e8-5f4c8ef806ac` (or similar) or `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`?

Comment: @dav_i I've tested and It's 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, so it's not an new Guid but an empty Guid.

Comment: Yeah makes sense, the default value for the type of  any property the binder can't detect is used.